# LLVM Find every instruction that allocates memory

Tags: c++, llvm

I want to find every instruction that allocates memory in LLVM IR. For stack allocations I simply do:

```
Instruction* I;      

if (AllocaInst* AI = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(I)) {
    //stack allocation
}
```

But what about heap and static (global) allocations?
What else can allocate memory in LLVM IR?

If the LLVM version makes a difference please provide the version you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately you won't be able to perfectly detect this. Heap allocations boil down to operating system calls and someone could directly make these calls with inline assembly. There are also library calls you won't have visibility to that are linked in.

Keep this in mind with whatever you're working on.

Comment: Not really.   +1 inline assembly implementation to making system call to allocate memory - that is possible.   But for system call that allocate memory, doing a "nm vmlinux|grep sys_" on my kernel, I can see only two perhaps - sys_brk() and sys_mmap().   not sure of the rest, but i don't think is a lot.   as for library call:   yes, different API in different library can allocate.   For eg, "malloc()" in libc is one of them.   So ignore the libraries, just focus on the system call, as malloc() is still basically calling brk().

Comment: He'll probably also want to know how to do this with non-linux kernels or non-posix systems, can you make that list?  Otherwise I think "won't be able to perfectly detect this" seems accurate.

Comment: Look up MemorySanitizer from Google:

https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm

https://github.com/google/sanitizers

And how it worked:   it just intercept on one function "malloc()", and is good enough to cover most of the memory allocation scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation can be either in stack and heap. For stack allocation what you are doing is right you need to check for alloca instruction. Heap allocation is done by malloc function calls there are no explicit IR instruction.

I din't do any experimentation with this but may be this is the way you can try.

```
    if(MemSetIntrinsic *MSI = dyn_cast<MemSetIntrinsic>(I))
           // This call instruction is a memory allocating instruciton
```

Comment: There is no point in nesting all these if, you can directly do the inner one test on the instruction. Also you should just find calls and check if the name of the called function is malloc.

Comment: Thanks for correction, I made changes accordingly. Checking the name of the function doesn't suffice, checking for "MemSetIntrinsic" is more generic way.

Comment: Malloc is not an intrinsic, the "MemSetIntrinsic" class wraps the llvm.memset intrinsic, which is not allocating memory (as the op asked).